# On my wordpress site I use the DHVC form plugin, is it possible to get the email data like an xml file?

Tags: wordpress, email, plugins

On my wordpress site I use the DHVC form plugin, is it possible to get the email data like an xml file?
Is there an option to get the email data from the contact forms like an xml file? is there some plugin I do not know about or some other solution? Thank you!